# Build Macros in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, macros

I am having a look at [Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) for building projects in Visual Studio. I am using a library nodejs that comes in various versions. It has a lot of dependencies. So every time i change the version of library, i have to manually change it everywhere from `include headers` to `library paths`.

Is there a way to add my own macro like `NODE_VER=0.10.0` ?